# Publicar proyecto en Cakephp3

Tags: cakephp

Estoy intentando subir mi proyecto a un servidor que me prestaron pero no estoy seguro como se hace ya subir el proyecto completo y veo que la principal tiene los textos pero los stylos y los links no funcionan (no esta en la raíz del hostigoso es un préstamo cree una carpeta aparte para no estorbar). Si alguno me guía para Cakephp3 para subir un proyecto cakephp a un servidor compartido ya que las guías que consigo son para el Cakephp2 y no parece ser los mismo pasos

Comment: Hola JLeo. Aqui esta pregunta es muy amplia. Has de buscar guias y documentacion por tu cuenta. O ya que tienes 20 de rep, entrar en el [chat] y preguntar ahi si alguien sabe. Mira [ask] y [help/on-topic] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b Si e buscado guias y mucha documentación pero con problemas ya que muchas se enfocan en cakephp2, el otro asunto es que yo no estoy colocando el proyecto en la carpeta raiz si no en una sub carpeta (ya que es prestado el espacio)